# Fonético específico en una variación centroamericana del sonido /s/ en los fines de sílabas

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación

He escuchado de bastantes centroamericanos (p. ej., unos vecinos nicaragüenses) una variación del fonético /s/ que aparece en los fines de sílabas, como en «vos comés» y «asqueroso», si me acuerdo bien. (Esto es el mismo acento que sustituye /ŋ/ como en «chancla» en lugar del fonético /n/ en los fines de palabras.) Se puede escuchar en el verso por Bad Bunny, un rapper puertorriqueño/boricuo, en la nueva canción [“I Like It”](https://youtu.be/xTlNMmZKwpA) por Cardi B (1:53).

Me parece que /s/ se convierte más o menos en /h/, el sonido de la jota como se pronuncia afuera de España. Otras veces (como en la canción) casi es como si no se pronuncie en lo más mínimo.

¿Alguien pudiera explicarme qué pasa en estos casos? ¿Cuál es (o cuáles son) el (los) fonético(s) específico(s) que se escucha(n) en estos casos?

*Se puede encontrar la gráfica IPA con sonidos [aquí](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/).*

<sub>*revisión: corregí* /x/ *a* /h/*, disculpe*</sub>

Comment: @walen creo que se refiere a la idea de que en España norte/central, la realización de "j" `/x/` no es velar sino [post-velar/pre-uvular o uvular `[χ]`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative)

Comment: @walen Yo quería enfatizar que el `x` en cuestión es muy muy suave, el opuesto de la jota española, que me suena como la che alemán. ¿Eso hace sentido, o no? Tal vez no lo expliqué (¿explicara?) bien.

Comment: El sonido velar /x/ no es "suave" en absoluto, y es de hecho el sonido de la *ch* alemana (en *ach*, no en *ich*). En España se usa más el uvular [χ] que suena aún más gutural.

Comment: Ay, pues ¡eso! Ustedes tiene razón, jajaja . . . o digo: *xaxaxa* ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se escucha en los finales de sílabas terminadas en /s/ es una aspiración, fonéticamente [h] (como la *h* del inglés), aunque en ocasiones directamente se trata de una elisión (es decir, /s/ es borrada totalmente).

Aspirar las *eses* finales es uno de los rasgos más comunes del castellano; lo hacen muchos dialectos, más en América que en España, aunque el andaluz es notorio por este rasgo. La aspiración de la *s* es muy variable. Puede ocurrir:

- Cuando /s/ cierra una sílaba, en todos los casos.
- Cuando /s/ termina una palabra pero sólo si la siguiente palabra empieza con consonante.
- Cuando /s/ termina una palabra, aunque la siguiente empiece con vocal.

Generalmente aspirar la /s/ se asocia al habla popular o al descuido al hablar, mientras que preservar el sonido "estándar" de la /s/ es más formal o del dialecto de prestigio. En ciertos dialectos, sin embargo, la aspiración de la /s/ en [h] es estándar, y pronunciarla como [s] puede sonar artificial o afectado.

En ciertas ocasiones la aspiración tiene efectos en la consonante que sigue: por ejemplo, la forma vulgar de pronunciar *resbalar* en español rioplatense es [refalar], donde la aspiración [h] ensordece y fricativiza la /b/ que le sigue.

Comment: Me pregunto: ¿Escuchaste el fragmento de la canción, o me comuniqué bastante bien para que me pudieras (¿pudiste?) entenderme sin ello?

Comment: Escuché la canción, pero desde antes ya suponía que se trataba de aspiración de la /s/, porque es muy característica.